# Extension for Entity Framework result

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working with Entity Framework and was wondering if there is a generic way to create extensions for query result.

For example I have a method :

```
    public static Student GetStudent(selector)
    {
         return _context.Student.Where(selector).FirstOrDefault();
    }
...
    public void DoSomeWork()
    {
     var student=GetStudent(x=>x.id=123);
     student.name="Tom";
     student.Save();  // <---- is there a way to create such an extension. 
                      //Not for Student Entity only but for all entities.
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with `_context.SaveChanges()` ?

Comment: Im just curious, if there's a way to make the save like this. Without making a SaveChanges()  method for every entity class .

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static Student GetStudent(Func<Student,bool> selector)
    {
         return _context.Student.Where(selector).FirstOrDefault();
    }
...
    public void DoSomeWork()
    {
     var student=GetStudent(x=>x.id==123);
     student.name="Tom";
     student.Save();  // <---- is there a way to create such an extension. 
                      //Not for Student Entity only but for all entities.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your EF repository should have a .tt file that is used to generate the EF Result classes. You can modify that file so that all of your EF Generated types implement an interface (of your choosing), you can then write your extension method for your chosen interface.